# How can PHP code use an APNS device token for Apple Push Notification?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I'm looking at the PHP code here:

https://gist.github.com/valfer/18e1052bd4b160fed86e6cbb426bb9fc

It looks good. I'd love to use it. But I'm confused about this:

```
 * @param $token            the token of the device
```

So I need the device token? For PHP code that is going to live on a server? How do I get the device token?

Answer (score -1):

when iOS application is started, it registers itself for Apple Push Notifications by using the following code in your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=8.0) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
        //register to receive notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

and then following delegate methods may be called based on success or failure

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
NSString* strdeviceToken = [[NSString alloc]init];
strdeviceToken=[self stringWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:strdeviceToken forKey:PREF_DEVICE_TOKEN];

[prefs synchronize];

NSLog(@"My token is===========> : %@",strdeviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
    // NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:@"" forKey:PREF_DEVICE_TOKEN];
[prefs synchronize];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        //        [self showToastMessage:@"Active"];
}
else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        //        [self showToastMessage:@"Background"];
}
else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        //        [self showToastMessage:@"Inactive"];
}

// [self handleIncomingNotification:userInfo delay:0.0];
}
```

All the above logic should be handled in `AppDelegate` class of your project. Then you can make some API call in your PHP code to be called from iOS and send this device token on your server and save it for future use.

Comment: Don't use `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414005-synchronize?language=objc) _"this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_